# K&R 1-9 // using getchar in a loop inside a loop

Tags: while-loop, eof, getchar, kernighan-and-ritchie

I have this simple program:

```
main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
            putchar(' ');

            if (c == EOF) break;
        }

        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

As I understand it, there are two loops. The condition for the first loop is for the output of `getchar` to be different then `EOF` (so implicitly the loop breaks at `EOF`); the condition for the second loop is that the output of `getchar` is not `blank`, then it'll output exactly one `blank` and if by any chance the non-blank character was `EOF` the whole program will interrupt.

Is it necessary to place a second check for `EOF`? Wouldn't it be "spotted" by the
 condition of the first loop?

How comes that the `blank` characters will be "consumed" by the second loop, but the first non-blank character is still there for the first `getchar` to be read?

Comment: for example if I input the string "this  example", the getchar in the outer loop would read the first blank, then the getchar in the inner loop would read a blank and the letter "e", then how comes that the letter "e" will be read also by the other getchar once the inner loop breaks?

Comment: after reasoning on the answer for the need of a break I guess that the putchar on the outer loop outputs the character read by the getchar in the inner loop...

Comment: yes to the second comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

The inner

```
if (c == EOF) break;
```

avoids the subsequent

```
putchar(c);
```

which would otherwise be performed if that cycle of the loop was completed.

---

e.g.

```
main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
            putchar(' ');
            if (c == EOF) break; // <<- This ...
        }

        putchar(c);             // <<- ... jumps past this.
    }
}
```

Comment: @maja, well, its a matter a style and subjective but I think it makes it easier to see the flow.

Comment: the second thing you wrote was the starting program, the exercise (I'm following a textbook) was to have the progra output only a single blank for any string of consecutive blanks in the input.

Comment: notice that the inner loop's getchar is followed by a `;` , that makes so that any "extra" white spaces will just be skipped until a different character is found.